# Rebinding exports in d3.js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm creating a map using the modules system. I'm more or less used to D3.js v3 but I am still getting used to v4.

I am trying to add a dispatch but I don't know how to rebind the exports in V4, as this function is not available now.

So for my dispatch (_dis) and my particular event ("changetype"), the rebind in d3 v3 would be right before returning the exports, for example:

```
d3.mapDots = function (districts){

   var _dis = d3.dispatch('changetype');

   (...)

   exports.color = function(_c){
       if(!arguments.length) return color;
       color = _c;
       return this;
   };    

   d3.rebind(exports,_dis,"on");
   return exports
   };
```

Does anyone know how to do this in v4? I've been trying dispatch.apply but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Good question. Looks like the dispatch object has somewhat [changed](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#dispatches-d3-dispatch), and that `d3.rebind` no longer exists. Because the latter is gone, it appears that there's no way to "copy" (via `d3.rebind`) the `.on()` method. Instead you must implement your own. [See here](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush/blob/master/src/brush.js#L533-L536) how bostock implemented `d3-brush`.

I put together [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/k5am14nc/1/) to demonstrate how to achieve with D3 v4 what you're asking.

The important bit is implementing the `.on` method:

```
instance.on = function() {
  var value = dispatcher.on.apply(dispatcher, arguments);
  return value === dispatcher ? instance : value;
}
```

And, dispatching is like this

```
dispatcher.call("was_clicked", this, "Hello, Foo!");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Now I understand how it works better... Although my dispatch is still not active. I have two different files (the main file script.js, and another one just for creating the map where the `exports.on = function()` is), do you think it may be because of that?

Thanks!

Comment: @Irene If I understood you question... It shouldn't matter that they're in different files. What matters is that `exports.on = function() {...}` lives within the instantiator function (in your case that would be within `d3.mapDots = function (districts){ ... }`). If that's the case, then them being in separate files shouldn't be a problem, as long as the main script properly imports the `mapDots` script (if you're able to call `d3.mapDots()` with no error then it is properly imported).

Comment: You should be able to make a jsFiddle that reproduces your issue, and that would help solve it.

Comment: Hi @meetamit, sorry I haven't been able to work on it until today. 
I've tried to do a fiddle that was more or less similar to my example [link](https://jsfiddle.net/inari_ta/jr5hwedn/1/). I am not even sure if  the code inside the dispatch is correct as I have an error saying that "mydispatch.changetype is not a function"

The dots are supposed to change of color depending on the color the user selects

Comment: ok, one friend looked at the code and he solved it. It was mainly because of two very stupid typos and the way I was calling the dispatch in the main script file. I was doing it by 
`d3.select(".type-list1").on("change",function(){
        dispatchmap1.changetype(this.value)
    });`
and it had to be `d3.select(".type-list1").on("change",function(){
        dispatchmap1.call("changetype",this, this.value)
    });`

Thanks!

Comment: Hey @Irene — glad it worked out. If you still have questions, let me know. Otherwise, if you don't mind, and if my answer qualifies, then please mark it as accepted and/or upvote (so that I can get some points...). Thanks